# Solr query data stream response in XSLT response writer

Tags: json, xml, csv, xslt, solr

Using Solr 8.2 with XSLT transformation in order to get a custom formatted CSV response.

Noticed that when using `wt=csv` or `wt=json` the data returned from the query are "streamed".

But, this doesn't happen when using `wt=xslt`; seems that it waits to load the response in (solr) memory > transform > send back formatted results.

So, my question is: is there a way to imitate this behaviour with XSLT response writer?

Thanks :)